# how to fix 404 error in my github web page? [github]

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

https://github.com/YRHwang90/portfolio

This is the repository that I want to make as a webpage.

The address of webpage of this repository is:

https://yrhwang90.github.io/portfolio/

However, I really tried hard but still could not figure out why it threw 404 errors.

FYI, the reference I referred is (https://datascience4psych.github.io/template_portfolio/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,
You need to keep a default **index.html** page in your current repository and also make sure your have given Github Username as repository name then It will 100% work for you

Then finally,
https://yrhwang90.github.io/portfolio/index.html

Comment: Index.html is in the "docs" folder. do I have to put that on to different path?

Comment: You need to put **index.html** file outside the docs folder

Comment: I put that out of it but it does not work so I just put that back..